# not able to getting the twitter home time line tweets

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter, ios6

In my app i want to get the tweets from twitter when not signed in to the twitter account in to the settings in iPhone. Actually i'm getting user tweets(i tweeted) only. But i want to get all followers tweets.

I'm using this url: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json

I change to this : http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json   an error occurred.
error is : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

I'm using this code.

```
- (IBAction)twitterButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.usernameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    self.nameString = self.usernameTextField.text;
    NSURL *timelineUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json"];

    NSMutableDictionary *parameters =
    [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [parameters setObject:self.nameString forKey:@"screen_name"];
    [parameters setObject:@"50" forKey:@"count"];
    [parameters setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];

    SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:timelineUrl parameters:parameters];

    [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         if (responseData != nil)
         {
             NSError *error = nil;
             self.dataSource = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

         NSLog(@" tweet inindex 0 %@",[self.dataSource valueForKey:@"text"]);

         NSLog(@"ghjgjhdgjhdgjsgdjgsdjg  %d",dataSource.count);

             if (self.dataSource.count)
             {
             [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(homeView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
         }
     }

 }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the response. it must be

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error]);
```

the response may be

```
{
    errors =     (
                {
            code = 215;
            message = "Bad Authentication data";
        }
    );
}
```

because home timeline is require Authentication.

Check how to get twitter with iOS 5

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-twrequest

but user must have signin in twitter.

If you don't want to use iOS 5 twitter, try to use other library  with oAuth , example https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];

SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestURL parameters:parameters];

postRequest.account = twitterAccount;
```